# Crashlytics is reporting wrong line numbers

Tags: android, google-fabric

In the past few weeks I've been seeing a lot of crashes with line numbers in the import statement lines.

For example this stacktrace with a crash at line 2

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected TLS version: NONE
   at okhttp3.TlsVersion.forJavaName(TlsVersion.java:2)
   at okhttp3.Handshake.get(Handshake.java:4)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:12)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:4)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:13)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:25)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:1)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:5)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:5)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:10)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:1)
   at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:22)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:10)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:1)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:22)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:10)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:5)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:10)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:1)
```

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: Facing the same problem, anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: @RamKoti https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android

Answer (score 0):

Using version 3.10.0.

Avoid using invalid HTTPS sessions. This prevents `OkHttp` from crashing with the error `Unexpected TLS version: NONE`.

Source: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/