# Why is one user getting NoSuchMethodError where tens of thousands don't?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can one of our many users get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
   at com.mycelium.wallet.activity.settings.SettingsPreference.getLanguage (SettingsPreference.kt:73)
   at com.mycelium.wallet.WalletApplication.onCreate (WalletApplication.java:109)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1127)
```

on this line of Kotlin code:

```
@JvmStatic
fun getLanguage(): String? = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.LANGUAGE_SETTING, Locale.getDefault().language)
```

There are three function calls on this line: `android.content.SharedPreferences::getString(String,String)`, `java.util.Locale::getDefault()` and `java.util.Locale::getLanguage()` all of which are available since API 1.

The only affected user (Samsung Galaxy A5(2017) (a5y17lte), 2816MB RAM, Android 8.0) tried to start the app 180 times with this insta-crash.

The conversion to Kotlin might have issues still?

Comment: Probably this device has a corrupt framework. If you have tens of thousands of users, this might not the only one such device. Besides, who would try to open an app 180 times to watch it crash?

Comment: The fact the user tried 180 times is why I care. This is a Bitcoin wallet, so ... he might have money in that wallet and I hate to not fix issues if I can. I suspect, catching this one will only let it crash somewhere else on his broken phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try { ... } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) { ... }` might be a suitable workaround. But they already might have given up; if you don't have any email address or alike, you won't be able to notify them. You'd could return a static string in case of a `NoSuchMethodError`. Besides, if one has written down the seed phrase, the wallet is on the block-chain, the device only has the keys. I'd file that as an individual destiny - and that device probably could still be rooted, to have the keys extracted. It's difficult to help them without having a support request, so that one could notify them of a new version, which not relies on whatever unknown method. Maybe they still use it and would receive an auto-update and try again, but only maybe - but there's no guarantee, that this is the only one unknown method on this device.

It's definitely not a Kotlin issue, but rather a storage defect; google "eMMC corruption".

And if the user has not written down their seed phrase, it's their very own fault.

This all is an assumption, but the probability isn't that low.

Answer (score 2):

As you know (I am sure) a `NoSuchMethodError` is caused by a mismatch between the versions of classes at compile time versus at runtime.

And, I agree with you that the three methods called by that line of code *should* be present at runtime.

I was a suspicious that there isn't a message string for the `NoSuchMethodError` to say which method was missing, but there are other examples for the Android platform where the message is missing.  So I am (tentatively) calling this not significant.

So we have to look for other explanations.  Here are some:

1. The line number in the stacktrace could be inaccurate.  People sometimes report this kind of thing; e.g. [Crashlytics is reporting wrong line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150654/crashlytics-is-reporting-wrong-line-numbers)
2. This particular user could be running a different (older?) version of your app where the code at that line is different to code you are looking at.
3. The user has "rooted" his device and messed around with its standard libraries.  Alternatively, the user's device has been hacked and the hacker has interfered with the standard libraries (rather crudely in this case).
4. The user has been messing with the bytecodes for your app and has accidentally got it trying to call a non-existent method.  Alternatively, the user is running a (crudely) trojaned version of your app where the bad guy has done the same thing.

The fact that your app involves Bitcoins means that there could be strong incentive for someone to be doing nefarious things ... so  the last two alternatives should not be discounted.

---

> The conversion to Kotlin might have issues still?

I don't see why that would affect only one user.

---

> The fact the user tried 180 times is why I care. This is a Bitcoin wallet, so ... they might have money in that wallet and I hate to not fix issues if I can.

(Or conversely, this might be a bad guy trying to get bitcoins out of a wallet via a stolen device.  The fact that the user is being so persistent ... *and hasn't contacted you for help* ... is suspicious in itself.)

But the point is that if you don't have any way to contact this user, fixing the issue in general is unlikely to help them directly.  And right now you don't have enough information to know what the problem really is.

Comment: Crashlytics can tell apart version numbers and the line-number matches the method names (I've looked). The probability that someone would intentionally mess around with framework libraries is rather low... a corrupted eMMC and the user not having written down their seed phrase seems to be the most likely reason behind this abnormality.